# How to avoid duplicate rows while do update and insert concurrency

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

I have this code:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public EarningService(IDbConnection db)
    {
        Db = db;
    }

    public async Task SomeMethodWithTransacion()
    {
        Db.Open();
        var tran = Db.BeginTransaction();

        try
        {
            string sqlInsert1 = "insert into someTable1";
            await Db.ExecuteAsync(sqlInsert1, new {param1});
    
            string sqlInsert2 = "insert into someTable2";
            await Db.ExecuteAsync(sqlInsert2, new {param2})
    
            var field1 = GetSomeField1(param);
       
            string updateQuery1 = @"UPDATE SOMETABLE1 SET someField = 'someValue' WHERE Id = @Id";
            Db.Execute(updateQuery1, new { Id });
    
            string sqlInsert3 = "insert into someTable3";
            await Db.ExecuteAsync(sqlInsert3, new {param3});
    
            var field2 = GetField2(param);
            var field3 = GetField3(param);
            var field4 = GetField4(param);
        
            string sqlInsert4 = "insert into someTable4";
            await Db.ExecuteAsync(sqlInsert4, new {param4});

            var sqlSP = "[AddAssets]";
            await Db.ExecuteAsync(sqlSP, new { @owner= @owner, @rvalue = value }, tran,
                   commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

            tran.Commit();
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            tran.Rollback();
            return 500;
        }
   }
}

//startup
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    string dbConnectionString = this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default");

    // Inject IDbConnection, with implementation from SqlConnection class.
    services.AddTransient<IDbConnection>((sp) => new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString));  
}
```

But I have a problem when the below code was executed:

```
var sqlSP = "[AddAssets]";
                await Db.ExecuteAsync(sqlSP, new { @owner= @owner, @rvalue = value }, tran,
                       commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Stored procedure :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddAssets] 
    @owner uniqueidentifier, 
    @rvalue nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @currentBal decimal = (SELECT TOP (1) [Balance] 
                                   FROM [dbo].[Assets] 
                                   WHERE [Owner] = @owner AND [Status]=1)

    IF @currentBal >= 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @assetTable TABLE
                            (
                                [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
                                [Owner] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
                                [Balance] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
                                [Status] [smallint] NULL
                            );

    INSERT INTO @assetTable 
        SELECT TOP 1 
            [Id], [Owner], [Balance], [Status] 
        FROM [dbo].[Assets] WITH (UPDLOCK) 
        WHERE [Owner] = @owner AND [Status] = 1;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Assets] ([Owner], [Balance], [Status])
    VALUES (@owner, @rvalue, 1)

    UPDATE [dbo].[Assets] 
    SET [Status] = 2  
    WHERE [Id] = (SELECT TOP 1 [Id] FROM @assetTable 
                  WHERE [Owner] = @owner);
END
```

I do load test the method using jmeter but got not expected result below :

| Id | Owner | Balance | Status | RV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3B09C822-E613-454B-A6AA-53FA68363F74 | 102.00 | 1 | 0x000000000007186D |
| 12 | 3B09C822-E613-454B-A6AA-53FA68363F74 | 103.00 | 1 | 0x000000000007186F |
| 13 | 3B09C822-E613-454B-A6AA-53FA68363F74 | 103.00 | 1 | 0x0000000000071871 |
| 14 | 3B09C822-E613-454B-A6AA-53FA68363F74 | 103.00 | 1 | 0x0000000000071873 |
| 15 | 3B09C822-E613-454B-A6AA-53FA68363F74 | 103.00 | 1 | 0x0000000000071875 |
| 16 | 3B09C822-E613-454B-A6AA-53FA68363F74 | 61.00 | 1 | 0x0000000000071877 |
| 17 | 3B09C822-E613-454B-A6AA-53FA68363F74 | 86.00 | 1 | 0x0000000000071879 |
| 18 | 3B09C822-E613-454B-A6AA-53FA68363F74 | 88.00 | 1 | 0x000000000007187B |
| 19 | 3B09C822-E613-454B-A6AA-53FA68363F74 | 77.00 | 1 | 0x000000000007187D |
| 20 | 3B09C822-E613-454B-A6AA-53FA68363F74 | 51.00 | 1 | 0x000000000007187F |

when I expected the result is only 1 row that have status = 1 for 1 owner :

| Id | Owner | Balance | Status | RV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3B09C822-E613-454B-A6AA-53FA68363F74 | 102.00 | 1 | 0x000000000007186D |
| 12 | 3B09C822-E613-454B-A6AA-53FA68363F74 | 103.00 | 2 | 0x000000000007186F |
| 13 | 3B09C822-E613-454B-A6AA-53FA68363F74 | 103.00 | 2 | 0x0000000000071871 |
| 14 | 3B09C822-E613-454B-A6AA-53FA68363F74 | 103.00 | 2 | 0x0000000000071873 |
| 15 | 3B09C822-E613-454B-A6AA-53FA68363F74 | 103.00 | 2 | 0x0000000000071875 |
| 16 | 3B09C822-E613-454B-A6AA-53FA68363F74 | 61.00 | 2 | 0x0000000000071877 |
| 17 | 3B09C822-E613-454B-A6AA-53FA68363F74 | 86.00 | 2 | 0x0000000000071879 |
| 18 | 3B09C822-E613-454B-A6AA-53FA68363F74 | 88.00 | 2 | 0x000000000007187B |
| 19 | 3B09C822-E613-454B-A6AA-53FA68363F74 | 77.00 | 2 | 0x000000000007187D |
| 20 | 3B09C822-E613-454B-A6AA-53FA68363F74 | 51.00 | 2 | 0x000000000007187F |

Please can someone assist me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you have complicated code, i have tried to write your same logic in another simpler code, and i have added WITH (rowlock,UpdLock) code to read updated value and lock the row till the end of the transaction:

try this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [AddAssets] 
(
    @owner      uniqueidentifier, 
    @rvalue     nvarchar(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @valid_balance_id as int;
    
    -- select last added
    set @valid_balance_id = (
        SELECT      TOP (1) 
                    [Id] 
        FROM        [Assets] WITH (rowlock,UpdLock) 
        WHERE       [Owner] = @owner  
                AND 
                    [Status] = 1 
        ORDER BY    [Id] DESC
    );

    -- if no value exit
    if @valid_balance_id is null 
    BEGIN
        return -1;
    END

    -- if selected id has balance >= 0
    set @valid_balance_id = (
        SELECT      TOP (1) 
                    [Id] 
        FROM        [Assets] WITH (rowlock,UpdLock) 
        WHERE       [Balance] >= 0 
                AND 
                    [Id] = @valid_balance_id 
    );

    -- if row has no balance or negative balance then exit
    if @valid_balance_id is null 
    BEGIN
        return -1;
    END

    -- set status = 2 for the valid value
    update  TOP (1)
            [Assets] 
    SET     [Status] = 2 
    WHERE   [Id] = @valid_balance_id;

    -- insert new value
    INSERT INTO [Assets]
    (
        [Owner], [Balance], [Status]
    )
    VALUES
    (
        @owner, @rvalue, 1
    );
END
```

Comment: This is a bad answer as it doesn't explain what you are doing differently or why it worked. If it works it's fine, but you can't really learn anything from this answer.

Comment: `till the end of the transaction` -> till the end of _what_ transaction? Shouldn't you add a transaction? A stored procedure isn't a transaction.

Comment: transaction in c# code calls the storeprocedure

Comment: Meh, I would still do that in the procedure, because (a) the C# code may change, and (b) someone might call the procedure _not from C#_. To me, it's kind of like having validation of e-mail format _only_ on the web page and not in the database, assuming that nobody would ever try to insert data from anything other than the web page (or manage to submit the form with Javascript disabled). I haven't worked with async but my experience with trying to make the application code handle all the database-intrinsic transaction logic has been far from stellar.